# How can execute multiple stored procedure One by One in Node js?

Tags: node.js

Below mention code iam using for executing multiple StoredProcedures One by One. becoz one procedure result depends on another.. after executing all procedures and collecting data page is rendering in node js..
is there any other way to do.. if yes please mention.

```
    connection = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
    connection.connect().then(function() {
        var request = new sql.Request(connection);
        console.log("select watchlist Procedure");
        return request.input('UserId', sql.Int, req.session.userId).execute('[dbo].[UDSP_SELECT_WATCHLIST]');
    }).then(function(result){
            watchlistData=result.recordsets;
            connection.close();
            connection = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
            connection.connect().then(function() {
            var request = new sql.Request(connection);
            console.log("Following Channel Procedure");
            console.log("Session UserId:::"+req.session.userId);
            return request.input('UserId', sql.Int, req.session.userId).execute('[dbo].[UDSP_SELECT_FOLLOWINGCHANNEL]');
        }).then(function(result){
            followingchannels=result.recordsets;
            usrfollChanId=[];
            for (var i in result.recordsets) {
                val = result.recordsets[i];
                for (var j in val) {
                    if(new String("PUBLIC").valueOf() != new String(val[j].Category).valueOf()){
                        usrfollChanId.push(val[j].ChannelId);
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log("usrfollChanId!!!"+usrfollChanId);
            connection.close();
            connection = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
            connection.connect().then(function() {
                var request = new sql.Request(connection);
                console.log("Trending videos Procedure");
                return request.execute('[dbo].[UDSP_SELECT_TRENDINGVIDEOS]');
            }).then(function(result){
                //console.log(result);
                trendingvideosData=result.recordsets;
                connection.close();
                var videoslist=[];
                connection = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
                connection.connect().then(function() {
                    var request = new sql.Request(connection);
                    console.log("Popular Channel Procedure");
                    return request.input('UserId', sql.Int, req.session.userId).execute('[dbo].[UDSP_SELECT_POPULARCHANNEL]');
                }).then(function (result){
                    console.log("in val");
                    //var recordCount=result.recordsets;
                    //channelVideoData = result.recordsets;
                    res.render('Home_New',{
                        recordsets:recordsets,
                        watchlistData:watchlistData,
                        followingchannelsData:followingchannels,
                        trendingvideosData:trendingvideosData,
                        popularchannelData:popularchannelData,
                        channelVideoData:result.recordsets,
                        usrfollChanId:usrfollChanId
                    });
                });
            }
        connection.close();
        });
    });
```